# Is there a way to add a conditional string in Python's advance string formatting "foo {}".format(bar)?

Tags: python, string

For example I have a line of code like this

```
if checked:
    checked_string = "check"
else:
    checked_string = "uncheck"

print "You can {} that step!".format(checked_string)
```

Is there a shortcut to this? I was just curious.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
print "You can {} that step!".format('check' if checked else 'uncheck')
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even know you could declare outputs from an if-then like that.

Comment: @hobbes3: That's not an if-then. That's Python's (bass-ackwards) ternary operator.

Comment: Not sure why everybody hates it so much... It seems very logical after getting over being used to the C/Java syntax.

Comment: I don't consider it to be wrongly-ordered at all. "My destination shall be the beach, if it is sunny, and otherwise the library." I cannot reorder this except by making "my destination" no longer the subject of the sentence (analogous to converting to an `if` block).

Answer (score 6):

This can be handled with python 3.6+ using f-strings

```
print(f"You can {'check' if checked else 'uncheck'} that step!")
```

Comment: To me this is most readable.

Answer (score 5):

```
checkmap = {True: 'check', False: 'uncheck'}
print "You can {} that step!".format(checkmap[bool(checked)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I know, I'm very late. But people do search.

I'm using this in a situation, where the format strings must be as simple as possible, because they are part of the user supplied configuration, i.e. written by people knowing nothing about Python.

In this basic form is the usage limited to just one condition.

```
class FormatMap:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = bool(value)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        skey = str(key)
        if '/' not in skey:
            raise KeyError(key)
        return skey.split('/', 1)[self._value]

def format2(fmt, value):
    return fmt.format_map(FormatMap(value))

STR1="A valve is {open/closed}."
STR2="Light is {off/on}."
STR3="A motor {is not/is} running."
print(format2(STR1, True))
print(format2(STR2, True))
print(format2(STR3, True))
print(format2(STR3, False))

# A valve is closed.
# Light is on.
# A motor is running.
# A motor is not running.
```